# Работа с focusout()

Tags: jquery, input

Как можно сделать, чтобы focusout() не срабатывал при нажатии на определенный блок?

Например, я использую такой код:

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function () {
    $(".mydiv").show();
});
$("input[type=text]").focusout(function () {
    $(".mydiv").hide();
});
```

При нажатии на любую часть сайта, происходит .focusout() и блок **.mydiv** скрывается.. мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на блок **.mydiv** не срабатывал .focusout().

Прошу помочь с вопросом, за ранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(event) { 
   if (event.target == document.getElementById(".mydiv")) {   
      event.preventDefault();  
      event.stopPropagation();   
      return false;   
   }
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать чуть более информативные ответы.

Comment: ваш код никак не может решить данный вопрос. Ибо речь идет о .focusout()

Comment: @Максуд: в чем проблема с focusout?

Comment: @cpp_user, Упс. Я ошибся, ваш код совершенно правильный, по крайне мере вопрос решен. Спасибо!

Comment: @cpp_user, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно еще дивы добавлять к  getElementById?  в jQuery например, добавляем таким образом 

`$("#mydiv1, #mydiv2, #mydiv3");`

Comment: @Максуд:var x = document.getElementsByName("animal");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = true;
    }
}